# Binary trees FindParent method doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, binary-tree, parent

Here is my BNode class

```
class BNode
{
    public int number;
    public BNode left;
    public BNode right;
    public BNode(int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

And here is my implementation of FindParent method in BTree class

```
 public BNode FindParent(BNode BNode, BNode searchNode)
    {
        if (searchNode.left == BNode || searchNode.right == BNode)
        {
            return searchNode;
        }
        if (searchNode.left != null)
        {
            return (FindParent(BNode, searchNode.left));
        }
        if (searchNode.right != null)
        {
            return (FindParent(BNode, searchNode.right));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is how i call it

```
    BNode bnodeFound = btree.Find(18);
    BNode bparent = btree.FindParent(bnodeFound, btree.rootNode);
```

[image: And here is how the tree looks like]

It returns null always, except when the number is the first root from the trees root. What i also found trough debugging is that it goes to the left-most root, checks that it has no right root and then returns null. Have tried to figure out this, but to no success. I use similiar way to find a number in the tree, and that works for finding 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `FindParent()` recursively each time for the left node (when it is not null), you are returning it directly which means the `FindParent()` for the right node will never be called.

```
// Assume we run this for the root node
if (searchNode.left != null)
{
    // If left node is not null, then it tries to find in left subtree only
    // Since it returns directly, whether found or not-found it WILL NOT
    // search in right sub-tree
    return (FindParent(BNode, searchNode.left));
}

// Unreachable code if left is not NULL
if (searchNode.right != null)
{
    return (FindParent(BNode, searchNode.right));
}
```

To fix you can remove the return statement and instead check if it is still not found.

```
if (searchNode.left != null)
{
    var found = (FindParent(BNode, searchNode.left));
    // Return if found, else continue to check in right
    if (found != null) return found;
}

// Checks in right sub-tree if not found in left subtree
if (searchNode.right != null)
{
    // While checking in right sub-tree, then return irrespective of whether
    // it was found or not found, since there aren't any more places to check
    return (FindParent(BNode, searchNode.right));
}
```

Comment: I removed the return calls, made so that it returns to a BNode returnNode and checked if it is not null and returned if it is not. Seems to work just fine, thanks!